# How to deploy my app to heroku when i have two different folders

Tags: node.js, angular, express, heroku

I have a project with two defferent folders.
One is frontend the another is back-end.
I want to deploy this both folders on one heroku app.

In the server.js i have

```
app.get('*', (req, res) => {
    return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../frontend/dist/index.html'))
})
```

so i can serve the index.html file from angular.But when i try to deploy withing git bash on the root of the folder,with that two fodlers i get errors that the language is not specified or something.I googled the error and people say that is because i don't have package.json file at the root of the folder.

How can i have two different folders and two different package.json so i can make deploy to heroku, or i can't ? what is the solution ?

Comment: Take all the code from the server directory and move it to the root directory.

Answer (score 1):

In your Node App `index.js` file add below code & move your client code inside client directory

```
  app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
  app.get("*", (req, res)=>{
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build",'index.html'));
  })
```

And in your Package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "client": "cd client && yarn start",
    "server": "nodemon server.js",
    "build": "cd client && npm run build",
    "dev": "concurrently --kill-others-on-fail \"yarn server\" \"yarn client\"",
    "start": "node server.js",
    "heroku-postbuild": "cd client && npm install && npm install --only=dev --no-shrinkwrap && npm run build"
  }
```

Comment: Should i have one package.json at the root only ?

Comment: NO Outside package.json for Noe js App, inside of client folder you will have another package.json

Answer (score 0):

The directory structure I find gives the least issues when deploying to Heroku is the following:

```
App (root)
|
|
+---client
|   |
|   +---...
|
+---models
+---routes
+---package.json (node)
+---Procfile
+---server.js (or index.js - definition dependent)
```

Your package.json (node) scripts should look something like this (keeping other custom scripts):

```
"scripts": {
  "start": "nodemon server.js",
  "heroku-postbuild": "npm install --prefix client && npm run build --prefix client"
}
```

Note: your client package.json scripts should remain relatively standard.

Procfile should be:

```
web: node server.js
```

...and as @Rahul Cv said, in your server.js (or index.js):

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "client/build")));
app.get("*", (req, res)=>{
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "client/build",'index.html'));
})
```